# Firebase Firestore iOS Multiple Models

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore and am struggling to try to find examples of projects with a few layers on iOS. I want to utilize all Firestore has to offer.

I have a user setup that maps Quizzes to a user. (All works perfectly) Now I want to build my Quiz structure. A Quiz object that has Questions and these questions have Answers.

I have built it to a certain level but it feels hacky. Can anyone share their best practice knowledge with me? It would be greatly appreciated.

Work so far:

**Firestore format:** "/quizzes/idone/questions/idtwo/questions"

```html
struct Quiz: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var title: String
  var score: Int?
  var completed: Bool
  @ServerTimestamp var createdTime: Timestamp?
  var userId: String?
  var questions: [Question]?
}
```

```html
struct Question: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var title: String?
  var completed: Bool?
  //TODO: Answers
}
```

```html
    do {
      var userQuiz = quiz
      userQuiz.userId = self.userId
        let questionOne = Question(title: "What day is it today?",
                                 imageName: "test.jpeg",
                                 completed: false)
        let questioTwo = Question(title: "What is the meaning of life?",
                                 imageName: "test.jpeg",
                                 completed: false)
      let _ = try db
            .collection("quizzes").addDocument(from: userQuiz) // Works perfect
            .collection("questions").addDocument(from: questionOne) // Here is the issue I can't add multiple questions.
    }
    catch {
      fatalError("Unable to encode quiz: \(error.localizedDescription).")
    }
```

```html
  private func loadData() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
    }
    listenerRegistration = db.collection(quizzesPath)
      .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: self.userId)
      .order(by: "createdTime")
      .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
          self.quizzes = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Quiz? in
            try? document.data(as: Quiz.self)
          }
          //Todo: This is the main part I have a issue at. How do I consume my questions and mapp them to quizzes
          let questions = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> [Question]? in
            try? document.data(as: [Question].self)
          }
          //self.quizzes.questions = questions
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to know best practices on data models and how to structure your data take a look at these two links [1] [2]. It also has videos as well that will be informative on getting you started with Firestore.

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

[2] https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data